# Preparing data for (stanford) Deepdive (ValueError)

Tags: postgresql, nlp, special-characters, stanford-nlp

I started using Stanford-Deepdive a while ago. 
I am currently facing the problem, that deepdive will interpret some of the rows he gets as incomplete.

```
Value Error: Expected 6 attributes, but found 5 in input row:
<Row()>
```

I already had this problem with another data-set. At this set there were some rows, that contained "\n" within the text. So i removed that and everything went flawlessly.

For my new set of data I am removing "\n", "\t", and any occurence of multiple spaces. Also I replace any empty text value by "EMPTY" - still the error refuses to go away.

Are there any other formatting errors or characters that I need to take care of?
Is my way of approaching this reasonable?

Comment: Got it!

In the original data there was one field that has only contained a single "\t".

In the process of preparing the data this one became a singular space. And later it would not have been seen as a valid entry in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was caused by a singular TAB (\t) entry. I replaced that by a singe SPACE and in the end it would not be a valid antry anymore

so if you use some text for deepdive you will want to treat etrys consisting of a single SPACE as if they were empty.